# "unknown key [] for create index"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am creating this Index, and I got an error.

I want to create an index of cities with names, people living, number of villages, facts about cities, etc.

My code is:

[IMAGE OF MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsQUc.png)

```json
PUT City-mk
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "CityID": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "CityName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "People": {
      "type":"integer"
    },
    "Fact": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "Villages": {
    "type": "integer"
  },
  "CallNum": {
    "type": "integer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add  the mapping/code snippet directly in question instead of image. It helps others in using that piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following corrections:

1. Index name must be in lowercase, so change City-mk to city-mk
2. Braces count was wrong
3. Subfields were defined wrongly- "fields": { "keyword": { "type": "keyword"  } }

```
PUT city-mk
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "CityID": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "CityName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "People": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "Fact": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "Villages": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "CallNum": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```